# Easiest way to create a sidebar component to only display based on a picklist field

Tags: lightning, configuration

My requirement is to create a sidebar component on the account object which will show a few fields that should only show if the program__c picklist field = card. i have done some searching and i am unsure of the best way of doing this. so far i attempted to create a compact layout and add the fields to it but then i am only allowed to assign it based on record type of the account, not a picklist field.

Comment: I think the problem you are facing is that components aren't currently updated when an object changes. It requires a page refresh for the component to see the change to the object. Either you can wait for the [push data cache invalidation feature](https://twitter.com/adam17amo/status/979438168507232256?lang=en) to be released (Spring '19) or you can add a "Check Again" button that will call a controller to check the current selected value on the object.

Comment: if you want to display and hide a component according to a certain field value, check this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5

Comment: I was actually able to do this using a related record lightning component and page layout.